# i am trying to develop a port scanner in python but my code is not giving any open port give me some suggestions about that?

Tags: python, sockets

This is my code it's just starting the scan but it is not completing ,where is the error in it. i need output as port number and port side by side.when i run in command prompt it gives like that,please give suggetions on that

```
from socket import *
import sys,time
from datetime import datetime

host =''
max_port=100
min_port=1

def scan_host(host,port,r_code=1):
    try:
        s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        code=s.connect_ex((host,port))
        if code==0:
            r_code=code
        s.close()
    except Exception,e:
        pass
    return r_code

try:
    host=raw_input("Enter Host address:")
except  KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n Application shtdown")
    sys.exit(1)

hostip=gethostbyname(host)
print("\n Host:%s IP:%s" %(host,hostip))
print("Scanning Started At %s...\n" %(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
start_time=datetime.now()


for port in range(min_port,max_port):
    try:
        response=scan_host(host,port)

        if response ==0:
            print("Port %d: Open" %(port))
    except Exception,e:
        pass
stop_time=datetime.now()
total_time_duration=stop_time -start_time
print("\n Scanning Finished At %s ..." % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
print("Scanning Duration:%s..." %(total_time_duration))
print("Have a nice day ...Sergeant Exploiter (Sploit)")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Making a Fast Port Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174743/python-making-a-fast-port-scanner)

Comment: Try the range 8000-9000. You need special privileges for the lower port numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Before using the following port scanner, you may want to check a few things first:

- Is the firewall on your computer blocking the port scanner?
- Is the device your computer connected to blocking certain ports?
- Is the computer you are trying to scan blocking ports with its firewall?
- Do you know the correct name of the host that you are trying to scan?
- Can you create a server on one computer and connect to it with a client on the other?

If none of the above points are cause for your problem, the program shown below may work for you:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import collections
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import operator
import socket

PURPOSE = 'Scan for open ports on a computer.'
PORTS = range(1 << 16)
POOL_SIZE = 1 << 8
TIMEOUT = 0.01


def main():
    """Get computer to scan, connect with process pool, and show open ports."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=PURPOSE)
    parser.add_argument('host', type=str, help='computer you want to scan')
    host = parser.parse_args().host
    with multiprocessing.Pool(POOL_SIZE, socket.setdefaulttimeout, [TIMEOUT]) \
            as pool:
        results = pool.imap_unordered(test, ((host, port) for port in PORTS))
        servers = filter(operator.itemgetter(0), results)
        numbers = map(operator.itemgetter(1), servers)
        ordered = sorted(numbers)
    print(f'Ports open on {host}:', *format_ports(ordered), sep='\n    ')


field_names = 'family', 'socket_type', 'protocol', 'canon_name', 'address'
AddressInfo = collections.namedtuple('AddressInfo', field_names)
del field_names


def test(address):
    """Try connecting to the server and return whether or not it succeeded."""
    host, port = address
    for info in itertools.starmap(AddressInfo, socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)):
        try:
            probe = socket.socket(info.family, info.socket_type, info.protocol)
        except OSError:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                probe.connect(info.address)
            except OSError:
                pass
            else:
                probe.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                return True, port
            finally:
                probe.close()
    return False, port


def format_ports(ports):
    """Convert port numbers into strings and show all associated services."""
    if ports:
        for port in ports:
            try:
                service = socket.getservbyport(port)
            except OSError:
                service = '?'
            yield f'{port:<5} = {service}'
    else:
        yield 'None'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```